# Where would the best place be keep your JWT security/secret key?

Tags: angular, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am busy developing a web application using .net core 2.1 and Angular, and I want to start implementing web tokens in the application to make it more secure.

I just want to know out of a security perspective where would the best place be to store you JWT security/secrete key in a web application?

Comment: Please , check it . https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: Best is subjective. There's tons of options. In general, you want something that supports encryption at rest. Other than that, you need to do your own research and make a decision for yourself.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67mezK3NzpU check out this fantastic talk on JWTs and many secure variations on how to store/use them!

Answer (score -1):

you can put security/secret key on Database and it needs you can fetch from database